# Trying to import my Postgres/Postgis database which is on a local Linux server for my docker project

Tags: docker-compose, postgis, qgis

I am in trainee in a company and my project is to use lizmap and qgis.

We can find the all project already docker-compose : https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-docker-compose

My real problem is how to put my postgres/postgis database into my project (.env and docker-compose.yml) which is located in the company's local Linux server.

I have access to my database with pgadmin and dbeaver without difficulty :

```
jdbc:postgresql://10.7.99.122:5678/crypteo
```

I try many thing in the .env and the docker-compose.yml :

```
LIZMAP_VERSION_TAG=3.6
LIZMAP_UID=1000
LIZMAP_GID=1000
LIZMAP_DIR=./lizmap
LIZMAP_PROJECTS=./lizmap/instances
QGIS_VERSION_TAG=3.28
QGIS_MAP_WORKERS=4
LIZMAP_PORT=8090
OWS_PORT=8091
POSTGIS_VERSION=13-3
POSTGIS_PORT=5432
POSTGIS_ALIAS=db.lizmap
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
# ajout de la base de donnés Postgres avec DB, User et Password"
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://crypteo:TgYETMWK%40xfP@10.7.99.122:5678/crypteo
# POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
# POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB=crypteo
# POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER=crypteo
# POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD="TgYETMWK@xfP"
# POSTGRES_HOST="10.7.99.122"
# POSTGRES_PORT=5678
```

Env :

docker-compose.yml :

```
  postgis:
    image: 3liz/postgis:${POSTGIS_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - { type: volume, source: postgis_data, target: /var/lib/postgresql/data }
      - { type: bind, source: "${LIZMAP_DIR}/etc/postgres.init.d", target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d }
    environment:
      # ajout du serveur linux crypteo :
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      # POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
      # POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      # POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB: ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB}
      # POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER: ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER}
      # POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${POSTGIS_PORT}:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d ${POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB} -q || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      start_period: 60s
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${POSTGIS_ALIAS}
```

But this is what i get at the end when i docker compose up :

1. When I use the first method currently commented out without "DATABASE_URL":

.env

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_DB=crypteo
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_USER=crypteo
POSTGRES_LIZMAP_PASSWORD="TgYETMWK@xfP"
POSTGRES_HOST="10.7.99.122"
POSTGRES_PORT=5678
```

When i docker compose up :

```
postgis-1  |
postgis-1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgis-1  |
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:05:59.090 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.13 (Debian 13.13-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:05:59.090 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:05:59.090 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:05:59.109 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:05:59.126 UTC [32] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-23 16:00:03 UTC
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:05:59.132 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgis-1  | 2024-01-23 16:06:39.131 UTC [72] FATAL:  database "crypteo" does not exist
```

or

When i use the secondary method :

.env :

```
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://crypteo:TgYETMWK%40xfP@10.7.99.122:5678/crypteo
```

When i docker compose up :

```
postgis-1  |
postgis-1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgis-1  |
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:17.787 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.13 (Debian 13.13-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:17.790 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:17.790 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:17.815 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:17.844 UTC [31] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-24 08:38:54 UTC
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:17.859 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgis-1  | 2024-01-24 09:22:37.634 UTC [53] FATAL:  database "-q" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

discard healthcheck, is it necessary?
and did you make the database crypteo?
or you have the user "crypteo"? wtih  ALL PRIVILEGES on database "crypteo?"